# php 5.1.6 magic __toString method

Tags: php, tostring, magic-methods

In codeigniter Im trying to use [this](http://www.overzealous.com/dmz/pages/extensions/htmlform.html) plugin which requires I implement a toString method in my models. My toString method simply does

```
public function __toString()
{
    return (string)$this->name;
}
```

On my local machine with php 5.3 everything works just fine but on the production server with php 5.1.6 it shows "Object id#48" where the value of the name property of that object should appear..... I found something about the [problem here](http://www.jcinacio.com/2007/04/19/phps-__tostring-magic-method-not-so-magic-before-520/) but I still dont understand... How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried return (string)$this->name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Upgrade PHP**

I'm dealing with the same problem, I suspect your best option will be to upgrade php on the production server to `>= 5.2.0`

In the future (I'm currently learning this the hard way), try to develop on the same version you will deploy to.

Answer (score 7):

```
class YourClass 
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

**PHP < 5.2.0**

```
$yourObject = new YourClass();
echo $yourObject; // this works
printf("%s", $yourObject); // this does not call __toString()
echo 'Hello ' . $yourObject; // this does not call __toString()
echo 'Hello ' . $yourObject->__toString(); // this works
echo (string)$yourObject; // this does not call __toString()
```

**PHP >= 5.2.0**

```
$yourObject = new YourClass();
echo $yourObject; // this works
printf("%s", $yourObject); // this works
echo 'Hello ' . $yourObject; // this works
echo 'Hello ' . $yourObject->__toString(); // this works
echo (string)$yourObject; // this works
```

Answer (score 3):

To quote from the manual:

> It is worth noting that before PHP
>   5.2.0 the __toString method was only called when it was directly combined
>   with echo() or print(). Since PHP
>   5.2.0, it is called in any string context (e.g. in printf() with %s
>   modifier) but not in other types
>   contexts (e.g. with %d modifier).
>   Since PHP 5.2.0, converting objects
>   without __toString method to string
>   would cause E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR.

I think you have call the __toString method manually if you're using it in PHP < 5.2 and not in the context of an echo or print.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly call the php magic function __toString() for versions < 5.2. So your code will become something like this:

```
    public function myname()
    {
       $name = $this->name;
       return $name.__toString(); //for php versions < 5.2,will also work > 5.2
    }
```

For versions > 5.2 the __toString is automatically called

Comment: I suspect you meant `$name->__toString();`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring` 
Need to change the PHP version as per your.

And after this do not forget to run `service apache2 restart`

Hope this will help.