# php toString not called when concatenate is used

Tags: php, concatenation, deprecated, tostring

referencing this post [php 5.1.6 magic __toString method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902182/php-5-1-6-magic-tostring-method)

```
class YourClass 
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

PHP < 5.2.0

```
$yourObject = new YourClass();
echo $yourObject; // this works
printf("%s", $yourObject); // this does not call __toString()
echo 'Hello ' . $yourObject; // this does not call __toString()
echo 'Hello ' . $yourObject->__toString(); // this works
echo (string)$yourObject; // this does not call __toString()
```

what other methods am i supposed to override 
to get the object to display properly in the context of string concatenates/etc

currently , i am getting something like

```
echo 'Hello ' . $yourObject;
```

produces 'Hello Object ID 55';

anyone has a solution in the context of :

- client doesnt want to upgrade their php version
- not splashing __toString all over the place

?

Comment: PHP < 5.3 is no longer officially supported. You are encouraged to upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: @Gordon wish I could upvote your comment a couple million more times ;)

Comment: Why did this get a down vote? it's a good question +1

Comment: @Ibu it's not a good question when it's easily answerable by RTFM.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the disclaimer in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)?

> It is worth noting that before PHP 5.2.0 the __toString method was only called when it was directly combined with echo() or print(). Since PHP 5.2.0, it is called in any string context (e.g. in printf() with %s modifier) but not in other types contexts (e.g. with %d modifier). Since PHP 5.2.0, converting objects without __toString method to string would cause E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR.

Since you're not *directly* involving the object with an echo (i.e. you're doing a concatenation operation first), the `__toString` method won't get called. So either upgrade your version of PHP, or explicitly call `__toString`.